# Category Tag Pair Vars not Parsing when Stashed into a Nested List

Tags: playa, categories, stash, parse-order

Coming across a parsing problem when trying to get related Playa entries categories in a nested list with Stash. The setup involves Playa pulling related entries (videos) from a parent entry (feed) as a Stash list, and then a nested list for each video to include the categories of each video.

**Example Code that stashes the data:**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="feed" dynamic="no" url_title="{segment_2}" limit="1"}

    {!-- The Feed --}
    {exp:stash:set name="feed_title"}{title}{/exp:stash:set}

    {!-- The Feed's Videos : Playa Field (Parent List) --}
    {exp:stash:set_list name="videos" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}

        {cf_feed_videos}

            {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
            {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
            {stash:file}{cf_video_file}{/stash:file}

            {!-- Video Categories : EE Categories (Nested List) --}
            {exp:stash:set_list:nested_cats name="categories_{entry_id}" context="{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}
                {categories}
                    {stash:category_url}{category_url_title}{/stash:category_url}
                    {stash:category_title}{category_name}{/stash:category_title}
                {/categories}
            {/exp:stash:set_list:nested_cats}

            {!-- Video Links : Matrix Field (Nested List) --}
            {exp:stash:set_list:nested_links name="links_{entry_id}" context="{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}
                {cf_video_links}
                    {stash:link_url}{mx_url}{/stash:link_url}
                    {stash:link_title}{mx_title}{/stash:link_title}
                {/cf_video_links}
            {/exp:stash:set_list:nested_links}

        {/cf_feed_videos}

    {/exp:stash:set_list}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**Example Code that outputs the data:**

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="videos" limit="1" sort="desc"}

    ...

    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <ul class="categories">
        {exp:stash:get_list:nested_cats name="categories_{entry_id}" context="{entry_id}"}
            <li><a href="{category_url}">{category_title}</a></li>
        {/exp:stash:get_list:nested_cats}
    </ul>

    ...

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

So everything parses correctly except for the variables within the nested categories loop.

The {category_title} for example renders as "{category_name}" as if it's not being parsed when it's stashed in the nested set_list.

I have tried setting a higher parse_depth on the parent set_list, or setting a parse_depth on the nested categories list, however these do not seem to work either. Also in the example code, there is a second nested list (video links) which is pulled from a matrix field at the same level of the categories nested list, and this renders just fine.

Is this a question of the EE {categories} tag pair parsing later in the process than custom fields like a matrix field?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the problem wasn't a parse issue after all. Playa disables categories by default so by placing a blank disable="" parameter on the {cf_feed_videos} tag it overrides this and re-enables categories for the related entries.